# Current Base Device UUID: does not match with stored UUID:

Tags: docker

Docker was malfunctioning so I restarted the service, the service does not start, I get the following error:

```
error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver \"devicemapper\" failed: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed: devmapper: Current Base Device UUID: does not match with stored UUID:696f3567-83d7-48d7-9675-688e8543534b. Possibly using a different thin pool than last invocation"
```

I understand that the workaround for this issue is deleting the contents of /var/lib/docker followed by a restart.

Is there any solution or workaround for this problem without deleting container data or images?

When I start docker in debug mode I get the following:

```
WARN[0002] devmapper: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Please use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `man docker` to refer to dm.thinpooldev section.
DEBU[0002] devmapper: activateDeviceIfNeeded()
DEBU[0002] devmapper: UUID for device: /dev/mapper/docker-253:1-134790422-base is:
DEBU[0002] devmapper: deactivateDevice()
DEBU[0002] devmapper: removeDevice START(docker-253:1-134790422-base)
DEBU[0002] devmapper: removeDevice END(docker-253:1-134790422-base)
DEBU[0002] devmapper: deactivateDevice END()
DEBU[0002] devmapper: Error device setupBaseImage: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed: devmapper: Current Base Device UUID: does not match with stored UUID:696f3567-83d7-48d7-9675-688e8543534b. Possibly using a different thin pool than last invocation
ERRO[0002] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed: devmapper: Current Base Device UUID: does not match with stored UUID:696f3567-83d7-48d7-9675-688e8543534b. Possibly using a different thin pool than last invocation
DEBU[0002] Cleaning up old mountid : start.
FATA[0002] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed: devmapper: Current Base Device UUID: does not match with stored UUID:696f3567-83d7-48d7-9675-688e8543534b. Possibly using a different thin pool than last invocat
```

Thank you

Best regards

Answer (score 4):

You can also delete the `UUID`, i.e.

```
{"next_device_id":1,"BaseDeviceUUID":"","BaseDeviceFilesystem":"xfs"}
```

and Docker will complete it when you next start the daemon.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had the same problem, the solution is look the actual UUID on /dev/loop0 with blkid

Example /dev/loop0: UUID="12345678-e192-482e-81c6-9f703db548b6" TYPE="xfs"

And the base device is configured in file *(/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/metadata/deviceset-metadata)*:

```
{"next_device_id":1,"BaseDeviceUUID":"**OLD-UUID**","BaseDeviceFilesystem":"xfs"}
```

Just change it!

And start the engine again... Your images and containers might have came back to you now!

Comment: This helped me today with the exact same error using devicemapper with NTFS under Fedora, thx!